# How to use a created Linux Kernel character driver from the commandline

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I've been following the tutorial on Linux Kernel programming over here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html

I've gotten to the section that is dedicated to "character device drivers" and while I've gotten it to compile, it will not function on the described case:

"Called when a process writes to dev file: echo "hi" > /dev/chardev"

I've tried several Linux console commands such as:

echo "hi" > sudo /dev/chardev/

and

sudo sh -c 'printf "hi" > sudo /dev/chardev/'

I'm running my code on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+

When I run the first command I will get nothing in return, and nothing is added to /var/logs/messages

When I run the second command I get:
sh:printf: I/O error

Full code over at: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html

I've modified the code with my snippet below.

```
/*  
 * Called when a process writes to dev file: echo "hi" > /dev/chardev
 */
static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", buff);
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is when I use echo "hi" > sudo /dev/chardev that in my /var/logs/messages a line will appear that simply says "hi".

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but did your run insmod to load the module?

Comment: Yes I have, I've also ran mknod /dev/chardev c <major_number> 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> echo "hi" > /dev/chardev

This is ok.

> echo "hi" > sudo /dev/chardev/

This is invalid. This will `echo hi /dev/chardev/` and write that to file named `sudo`. And don't `/dev/chardev/`, it't not a directory, it's a file, it's `/dev/chardev` (without the `/` on the end).

> sudo sh -c 'printf "hi" > sudo /dev/chardev/'

Same error as above.

If you want to append to a file using sudo, use `tee`, as in `echo hi | sudo tee /dev/chardev`. Or if you have to `sudo sh -c 'echo "hi" > /dev/chardev'`.

Comment: When I use sudo sh -c 'echo "hi" > /dev/chardev' I get: sh: echo: I/O error and when I use echo hi | sudo tee /dev/chardev I get: tee: /dev/chardev: Invalid argument. Also none of them appear in /var/log/messages

Comment: `Also none of them appear in /var/log/messages` - why should it/they, `/var/log/messages` is just a file, it is unrelated to kernel. (see syslog-ng, nsyslogd and other syslog programs). You should check `dmesg` as the most reliable way of querying kernel ring buffer.  Nowadays people use `journalctl` and there is not `/var/log/messages` file at all. `I/O error` - you return `return -EINVAL;` from your write function, what would you expect? User application interprets that as an error. Or you failed to property register character device for your driver.

Comment: The error by `tee` : `tee: /dev/chardev: Invalid argument.` explicitly says that errno was set to `-EINVAL`, see `errno EINVAL`.

Comment: I'd assume that Hi would appear in the log as I'm attempting to print it using klog() ?

Comment: I don't know any function named `klog()`. You used `printk()` in your module, which appends the data to kernel ring buffer. You can query the ring buffer from user space using `klogctl()`. Or it's popular to query the kernel ring buffer using `dmesg` command. If (and only if) you have a syslog program configured to append kernel messages to the file `/var/log/messages` then will kernel messages appear there. I don't know about your configuration, and I can guess you are using journalctl and not syslog services. Check `journalctl -k`